# Unable to access Jenkins (Centos 7)

Tags: linux, networking, centos, centos7, jenkins

I've just installed Jenkins with its default configs on a Centos 7 physical box.

Port 8080 is open on the firewall:

```
sudo iptables -L -n
[...]
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8080
[...]
```

It also looks like Jenkins is actually listening on all interfaces:

```
sudo netstat -an | grep "LISTEN "
[...]
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN
[...]
```

I can `curl localhost:8080` locally (from the Centos box) without a problem, but from anywhere else in the network I get a `Connection refused`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: looks like it's only listening in ipv6.

Comment: It's listening on IPV4 now. Still can't connect.

Comment: could you disable selinux and try again? setenforce 0 as root sets it in permissive mode temporarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above looks like Jenkins is defaulting to ipv6 only.

Try the following, this will probably fix your problem:

run:
`$ /sbin/sysctl net.ipv6.bindv6only`

You will probably get an output with value `net.ipv6.bindv6only = 1`.

If this is the case, you will need to disable the setting:

`sudo /sbin/sysctl net.ipv6.bindv6only=0`

After the command above you will get an answer like `net.ipv6.bindv6only = 0`, restart Jenkins: `sudo systemctl restart jenkins` and try to connect to Jenkins again.

If this worked for you, you should put this in a sysctl config-file. Because this is not a persistent fix. After a reboot the setting you just have modified will be defaulted to *1* again.

Check `/etc/sysctl.conf` and `/etc/sysctl.d/*` and add `net.ipv6.bindv6only = 0` in order to make this setting permanent and run `sudo sysctl -p` or restart after changing it.

Comment: In Centos the bind can only show ipv6 entry while it is in reality bound to both ipv4 and ipv6.

Comment: Apparently Java was configured to use IPV6 by default, so I forced it to use IPV4 by adding `JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="$JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"` to `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins` and now I do get the correct answer from netstat:  `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN `.  I still can't connect to Jenkins, though. Do I need to specify a hostname for Jenkins or does it listen on 8080 regardless of the hostname?

Comment: I'm coming to the conclusion that the culprit here is the firewall/IP tables, no Jenkins. Even when I spin up a web server on port 8081 (or even 80) I don't get connection from the outside.

Comment: @Panos since it is a Centos 7 machine, could you try the following (unless you disabled the firewalld service and use plain iptables):

`firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8080/tcp --permanent`
`firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-service=http --permanent`
`firewall-cmd --reload`

Comment: Nothing :( Neither 80 nor 8080 working. Actually, even with the firewall down and iptables disabled I still don't get to connect through those ports. I can still ping the server and ssh into it... This is insane...

Comment: @Panos, so:

1. Jenkins is loaded `systemctl status jenkins`: `systemd[1]: Started LSB: Jenkins Automation Server.`

2. Java listens to port 8080, `lsof -u jenkins -a -i :8080 -P`:
`java    5124 jenkins  161u  IPv4  74141      0t0  TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)`

3. You disabled the firewall and still not working.

4. You can SSH and Ping to the server, trough the same IP.

I installed Jenkins on a fresh machine, first it didn't work also, used the steps above and it worked. Maybe an external firewall not allowing 80 or 8080 to that IP?

Comment: So, I ended up doing a `sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-service=http` and got to open port 80, at least. I'm clueless as to why this didn't work when I had `firewalld` down... Gosh, Centos... [I'll go back to the Jenkins part tomorrow, cause this whole firewall thing was a killer]

Comment: This is a good article in order to install Jenkins and Centos 7, this also can help you further: [How to install Jenkins on Centos 7](https://hostpresto.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-jenkins-on-centos-7/)

Answer (score 4):

@panos : it worked after setting JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="$JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" in /etc/sysconfig/jenkins then sudo systemctl restart jenkins. also i removed ipv6 entries in /etc/hosts not sure if the file needs to be edited, later i checked "netstat -tulpen" can see java is listening on tcp..

Comment: In case of an Ubuntu based machine the Jenkins settings will be on /etc/default/jenkins